# Find the expected value of the matrix

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, trigonometry

$\require{cancel}$
I want to see if I have solved this problem appropriately or not.
If we have
$$[C_\beta(2\theta)]=\frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix}-2\cos2\theta&\sqrt{2}\sin2\theta&0\\\sqrt{2}\sin2\theta&0&\sqrt{2}\sin2\theta\\0&\sqrt{2}\sin2\theta&2\cos2\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$p(\theta,\theta_0,n)=\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\cos^{2n}(\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{2})$$
where $-\pi\le\theta\le\pi$ and $-\pi\le\theta_0\le\pi$ is the mean orientation angle and $n\in\mathbb Z\,,\,n\ge0$
Find the expected value of $[C_\beta(2\theta)]$ in the form $f(n)[C_\beta(2\theta_0)]$?

We have
$$EX([C_\beta(2\theta)])=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[C_\beta(2\theta)]p(\theta,\theta_0,n)\,d\theta$$
Then:
$$\begin{align}
EX_{11}
&=-EX_{33}\\
&=-\frac{2^{2n-3}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos2\theta\cos^{2n}(\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{2})\,d\theta\\
&=-\frac{2^{2n-2}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\int_{\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2}}^{\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}}\cos(4x+2\theta_0)\cos^{2n}x\,dx\\
&=-\frac{2^{2n-2}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\times\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\cancel{\int_{\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2}}^{\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}}\cos(4x+2\theta_0)dx}\\
&-\frac{2^{2n-2}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\times\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\int_{\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2}}^{\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}}\cos(4x+2\theta_0)\cos(2n-2k)x\,dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{4\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\int_{\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2}}^{\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}}\left(\cancel{\cos[(4+2n-2k)x+2\theta_0]}+\cos[(4-2n+2k)x+2\theta_0]\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{4\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\binom{2n}{n-2}\int_{\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2}}^{\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}}\cos2\theta_0\,dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{4}\frac{\frac{2n!}{(n+2)!(n-2)!}}{\frac{2n!}{n!n!}}\frac{\pi\cos2\theta_0}{\pi}\\
&=\frac{-1}{4}\frac{n!n!}{(n+2)!(n-2)!}\cos2\theta_0\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}\left(\frac{-2}{8}\cos2\theta_0\right)\Rightarrow EX_{11}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}[C_\beta(2\theta_0)]_{11}
\end{align}$$
from integration by substitution method $x=\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{2}\Rightarrow d\theta=2dx,\theta=2x+\theta_0$
Interval$=\left[\frac{-\pi-\theta_0}{2},\frac{\pi-\theta_0}{2}\right]$
$\cos^{2n}x=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\cos 2(n-k)x$
$4-2(n-k)=0\Rightarrow n-k=2\Rightarrow k=n-2$
We can prove the same way that for every element of $EX$ we have $EX_{nm}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}[C_\beta(2\theta_0)]_{nm}$
so $$\bbox[border:2px solid red]{EX([C_\beta(2\theta)])=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}[C_\beta(2\theta_0)]}$$